# Combining functions to one button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have a single button that says, "Viewer One" and is tied to a  section with the ID, "viewer_one".  When the user clicks the button, I would like it to change to show, "Viewer Two" and also show the  section with the ID "viewer_two" in place of where the other nav had been.  Each time the button is clicked it will switch to the other.

I have two sets of script that perform each function individually, but I cannot figure out how to make them work at same time.  At moment, I can either have a button that changes its value on click but does not impact the rest of the code or I can have the button impact the rest of the code but its own text does not change.

I have included my code below - I have included both sets of javascript so that you can see what I have but they only work when I include one or the other - I need help figuring out how to get them to work together.

Below is a condensed version of the code to the pertinent parts - the main code has several more list items for each viewer.

```js
    
       <!--  this gets the button click to change which list is visible-->
 
 function switchVisible() {

            if (document.getElementById('viewer_one')) {

                if (document.getElementById('viewer_one').style.display == 'none') {

                    document.getElementById('viewer_one').style.display = 'block';

                    document.getElementById('viewer_two').style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {

                    document.getElementById('viewer_one').style.display = 'none';

                    document.getElementById('viewer_two').style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
   }          
    
    
   <!--This gets the button text to change-->

          function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("Button1");
            if (x.innerHTML === "Viewer Two") {
              x.innerHTML = "Viewer One";
              } else {
                x.innerHTML = "Viewer Two";
                    }
      }
```

```html
         <section id="second_nav">      
      <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Viewer One" onclick="switchVisible();"/>         
      <button id="Button1" onclick="myFunction()">Viewer One</button>          
      <nav class="viewer_nav" id="viewer_one">
        <ul>
          <li style="color: blue;"><b>VIEWER ONE:</b></li>
          <li><a href="#client1">Client Info</a></li>
          <li><a href="#scripts1">Scripts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>          
      <nav class="viewer_nav" id="viewer_two">
        <ul>
          <li style="color: blue;"><b>VIEWER TWO:</b></li>
          <li><a href="#client2">Client Info</a></li>
          <li><a href="#scripts2">Scripts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
    
    <div id="content_area">     
      <section class="viewer_class" id="view_area_one">
        <h3 class="viewer_title" style="text-align: center;">VIEWER ONE</h3>
        <span id="client1"></span>
        <h4>Client Info</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <span id="scripts1"></span>
        <h4>Scripts</h4>
        <p>Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Turpis in eu mi bibendum neque.</p>
      </section>
  
     <section class="viewer_class" id="view_area_two">
       <h3 class="viewer_title" style="text-align: center;">VIEWER TWO</h3>
        <span id="client2"></span>
        <h4>Client Info</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <span id="scripts2"></span>
        <h4>Scripts</h4>
        <p>Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Turpis in eu mi bibendum neque.</p>
     </section>
```

No error messages, but I can only get one or the other to work, not in combination.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var currentViewer = 1
updatePage(currentViewer)

function switchViewer() {
  if (currentViewer === 1) {
    currentViewer = 2
  } else if (currentViewer === 2) {
    currentViewer = 1
  }
  updatePage(currentViewer)
}

function updatePage(viewer) {
  switch(viewer) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById('viewer_one').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('viewer_two').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('view_area_one').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('view_area_two').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('switchViewerButton').innerHTML = "Viewer 2"
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById('viewer_one').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('viewer_two').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('view_area_one').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('view_area_two').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('switchViewerButton').innerHTML = "Viewer 1"
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="second_nav">
  <button id="switchViewerButton" onclick="switchViewer()">Viewer One</button>
  <nav class="viewer_nav" id="viewer_one">
    <ul>
      <li style="color: blue;"><b>VIEWER ONE:</b></li>
      <li><a href="#client1">Client Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="#scripts1">Scripts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav class="viewer_nav" id="viewer_two">
    <ul>
      <li style="color: blue;"><b>VIEWER TWO:</b></li>
      <li><a href="#client2">Client Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="#scripts2">Scripts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>

<div id="content_area">
  <section class="viewer_class" id="view_area_one">
    <h3 class="viewer_title" style="text-align: center;">VIEWER ONE</h3>
    <span id="client1"></span>
    <h4>Client Info (view_area_one)</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <span id="scripts1"></span>
    <h4>Scripts</h4>
    <p>Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Turpis in eu mi bibendum neque.</p>
  </section>

  <section class="viewer_class" id="view_area_two">
    <h3 class="viewer_title" style="text-align: center;">VIEWER TWO</h3>
    <span id="client2"></span>
    <h4>Client Info  (view_area_two)</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Some other text...</p>
    <span id="scripts2"></span>
    <h4>Scripts From V2</h4>
    <p>Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Turpis in eu mi bibendum neque.</p>
  </section>
```

Here's my version - I separated out the logic for controlling which viewer is currently visible from the code that changes the DOM, so you can more directly see how the current viewer changes the content of the page. I also didn't fully understand what you wanted to change on the button press, I've made it a content toggle as that seemed to be what you were going for? Your example only toggles the navbar. Let me know how this suits you.

Comment: Thanks James - yes, I did want only the nav bar changing.  I have linked each nav bar to items in the viewer divs - it's sort of a work around for making one viewer active at a time, but still keeping both on the screen at the same time.

Comment: Your solution is almost perfect for me.  I just want to remove the change to the actual viewers and keep it limited to the 2 navigation divs.  The idea is that they will be able to know which viewer is linked to the list items - and switch back and forth between them.  If it works, I would remove the <li>Viewer One</li> and the one for two as they would no longer be needed since the button would tell the user which list was being displayed.

Comment: Thank you James - I was able to make a few tweaks to what you provided and now have it working properly.  Was totally stuck on that one.  thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So, If you want both to work together, write your javascript code as:

```
<!--  this gets the button click to change which list is visible-->

 function switchVisible() {

<!-- Your Code -->

}

<!--This gets the button text to change-->

 function myFunction() {

<!-- Your Code -->

}

<!-- My Code -->

window.onload = function(){
  const button = document.querySelector("#switchViewerButton");
  if (button) {
     button.onclick = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        switchVisible();
        myFunction();
     }
  }

}
```

And Replace the HTML line

```
<button id="switchViewerButton" onclick="switchViewer()">Viewer One</button>
```

with the line

```
<button id="switchViewerButton">Viewer One</button>
```

I hope it should work. Please comment if you face any problem in implementing the solution.

Comment: Thanks Yatin.  Unfortunately, this did not work.  Do you know how to add a screen shot to this site - it would probably help a lot in explaining what I want to happen.

Comment: In "Edit Answer" window, under the Body section, there is a toolbar on the top. There you can find the image icon, clicking on which you can add the screenshots.